# The best host server for running a C program?

Tags: c, web-hosting

I have developed automatic speech recognition software with C, and would like to develop a web application using that.
But I have no idea where should be the best host server that I can run it.
I really want to run it on Google App Engine, but as far as I know it allows only Java and Python.
So I would be appreciate if you could recommend decent or popular host servers for this purpose.

Comment: Try this host https://www.cloudways.com/en/?id=806802 
I believe that  the best host server for running your C program. I used it and it's really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon's [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) lets you deploy operating systems of your choice, where you can run programs in programming languages of your choice. Smaller competitors are Google's [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) and Microsoft's [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at Amazon Web Services:
http://aws.amazon.com/